# Action bar not visible in my Activity ?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I'm using android studio 1.3.1.
i trying to add Option menu in my mainActivity.But it is not visible,when i run the application.
I have attached the code. please look into it.

Following code in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button sms;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //xml inflation
    sms=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sms);

sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SMSActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    //xml inflation for option menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id=item.getItemId();
    switch(id)
    {
        case R.id.menu_contact :
            Intent i=new Intent(this,ContactActivity.class);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_exit:
            this.finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

Following code in main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#59c5ff"
android:id="@+id/LinerarLayout1"
android:orientation="vertical">


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="SMS"
    android:id="@+id/sms"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Following code in menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item   android:id="@+id/menu_contact"
        android:title="Contact us"
        android:showAsAction="never">
</item>

<item   android:id="@+id/menu_exit"
        android:title="Exit"
        android:showAsAction="never">
</item>
</menu>
```

can anyone help me on this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try `getActionBar().show();`? Also if you want you could change the `extends Activity` to `extends AppCompatActivity` Also.. if nothing worked try to change the `showAsAction` to ifRoom

Comment: Check your theme, perhaps your app is using a theme without Action Bar

Comment: I think it's your theme problem. Post your style.xml

Comment: Check [here](http://androhub.com/android-actionbar-and-option-menus/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Change `extends Activity` to `extends AppCompatActivity`.

Secondly, your style.xml should be somewhat like this :-

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       ...
 </style>
```

This would doo. Cheers!

Comment: I just extends the AppCompactActivity in my MainActivity and it works..    thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Please do as following solutions:
1. Apply theme in activity OR application in manifest:
android:style

```
Theme.Holo.Light
```

OR

```
"Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```